# Is there a complete reference / documentation of Spring annotations?

Tags: spring, annotations

For instance, if I open the *Spring Framework Reference Documentation* and open *5.9.2. @Autowired*, I get [this explanation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.10.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation): *As expected, you can apply the @Autowired annotation to "traditional" setter methods:*.

Not very informative. Actually, the explanation assumes prior knowledge given that I'm expected to have certain expectations.

So is there complete reference of annotations somewhere?

Comment: Are you looking for this, or something more in depth? http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/pdf/spring-framework-reference.pdf

Comment: The problem is, that documentation doesn't really contain such a reference. As an example, the definition of @AutoWired actually tells you nothing about what it is or does.

Comment: You'll probably want to take a look at the Javadoc of each annotation. For example http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html

Comment: I think you are looking for something that suits your particular requests, whereas the documentation is meant for a wider audience and IT does make sense to read to rest of it to have "prior knowledge" and understand `@Autowired`, for example.

Comment: Geo: Ahh yes, the javadoc works much better. I looked there but couldn't find it. New to this...

Answer (score 2):

DZone had a refcard about Spring Annotations a good while back so its not the most up to date but this might still be useful to you - http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/spring-annotations

You will need to quickly create an account if you dont have one (free by the way) but its worth it for all the other refcards anyway.

I think the official spring documentation is very good but ya you cant just jump into a section like 5.2.9 without prior knowledge of the how the dependency injection framework works etc.

And btw, the refcard was written by Craig Walls who is the author of the Spring in Action book series so you can be confident that the document is correct (albeit dated).